# Android Application saving data when app in background

Tags: android, background-process, data-storage

currently I'm developing xmmp client which is working quite fine when app is in foreground. But due to the fact that im keeping quite lot of data in Application class (complex ArrayList, Strings and booleans as public statics) when app is in background every field is being garbage-collected.

So my question is what is the best way to retrieve this data when i get app from background? Its quite a problem because I use this public statics in every class so far and it causes my app to crash. The problem is the fact that user can put app in background from every activity and repopulating data in Application class seems like something hard. Maybe there is another way of keeping data with global access to them, that wont be wiped down in background?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is that your app is destroyed by android when in backgroud, the standard way to do would be to save data in the onDestroy() function of your main activity, and retrieve this data in the onCreate method when to app is opened again ( using the bundle).

If you want the data to persist even when the phone is turned off, you can considere permanent storage options like a database. Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Finally, if you would like a way to keep running in background, you could have a look at the Service class. But if would demand some more coding from you to be able to communicate between your service and the activity

Comment: So if i use service and in the service i would keep my data they will be kept untouched to the moment i will stop this service? It sounds like a great idea, but im worried about activity-service communication. How would i achieve that? Any example would be appreciated

Comment: Yes, you can start the service in such way that it will keep running until you stop it, even if your activity stopped. For the service to activity communication, you can use an Ibinder (I've never done it actually), or use a LocalBraodcastManager. This is a bit less efficient, but it is easy to use and keeps your data private in your app (better than broadcast). You have a complete tutorial here: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/using-localbroadcastmanager-in-service-to-activity-communications/

Comment: Great. Thanks for this tutorial but i have one concern. How to pass data from service to listener? In this moment i use public static object of list to iterate and change it or adaper to refresh it. So how to send back changed object to service is it possible to do?

Comment: What do you mean, "from service to listener"? I think the LocalBroadcastManager is what you need

Comment: Well, maybe couple of information will help. So im developing a xmpp messanger. I have listener which receives messages from xmpp service and add them to specific chat list. The chat list i use is now a public static array list with is kept in Application class. Now as i mentioned before i want to make a service which will kept data. So listener interates over that chat list and it changes it(add new messages). So i want to somehow get this list from service and add some changes to it, but changes should be available so in another activity where i use list again has right data

Comment: Ok, so maybe your listener could use LocalBroadcastManager to send the data to the service, and then the service manages the data

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sharedpreferences see following example

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/