# How to properly put onPause() and onResume() methods in my game

Tags: java, android

I am making a game in surface view, and what i am trying to achieve is to pause the game if the home button is pressed and when the game is opened again resume from exactly where game play stopped

I have looked at several similar questions here and none is giving me what i want, perhaps because our code structures are different

my codes are added below, i have removed a good part of the code that i don't feel would be relevant, but if anyone needs it i would add it

**GamePanel.java**

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){

    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
    //we can safely start the game loop
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
    boolean retry = true;
    int counter = 0;
    while(retry && counter<1000)
    {
        counter++;
        try{thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
            thread = null;
        }catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }

}

public void update()

{
    if (playing) {
        double fuelUsed = (player.getFuel() / PHYS_FUEL_MAX ) * thread.UI_BAR;

        if (fuelUsed > thread.mFuel) {
            fuelUsed = thread.mFuel;
        }
        thread.mFuel -= fuelUsed;
    }

        if(player.getPlaying()) {

        if(botborder.isEmpty())
        {
            player.setPlaying(false);
            return;
        }

        bg.update();
        player.update();
        fuelsmall.update();
        fuelbig.update();
        fuelnegative.update();
        if(collectFuelSmall(player, fuelsmall)){
            player.fuel +=500;
        }
        if(collectFuelBig(player, fuelbig)){
            player.fuel +=1000;
        }
        if(collectFuelNegative(player, fuelnegative)){
            player.fuel -= 250;
        }
    else{
        player.resetDY();
        if(!reset)
        {
            newGameCreated = false;
            startReset = System.nanoTime();
            reset = true;
            disappear = true;
            explosion = new Explosion(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.explosion),player.getX(),
                    player.getY()-30, 100, 100, 25);
            player.fuel=3500;
        }
    if (player.getScore() > getBestScore()) {
        setBestScore(player.getScore());
    }
    }
```

**MainThread**

```
public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GamePanel gamePanel)
{
    super();
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.gamePanel = gamePanel;

}


@Override
public void run()
{
    long startTime;
    long timeMillis;
    long waitTime;
    long totalTime = 0;
    int frameCount =0;
    long targetTime = 1000/FPS;

    while(running) {
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        canvas = null;

        //try locking the canvas for pixel editing
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {


                this.gamePanel.update();
                this.gamePanel.draw(canvas);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        finally{
            if(canvas!=null)
            {
                try {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
                catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }




        timeMillis = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
        waitTime = targetTime-timeMillis;

        try{
            this.sleep(waitTime);
        }catch(Exception e){}

        totalTime += System.nanoTime()-startTime;
        frameCount++;
        if(frameCount == FPS)
        {
            averageFPS = 1000/((totalTime/frameCount)/1000000);
            frameCount =0;
            totalTime = 0;
            System.out.println(averageFPS);
        }
    }
}
public void setRunning(boolean b) {
    running=b;
}
}
```

**Game.java**

```
public class Game extends Activity {

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}
}
```

i have tried to set thread.setRunning(false),
 for the onPause() but the game crashes

please can someone guide me to a solution

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2**

When HOME is pressed the application goes background and I think the application doesn't run further (unless you specified that in the code), and when the app goes foreground its state will be the same it was before going background unless the system has killed it to get resources.

See:

- https://godotengine.org/qa/3643/android-pause-game-when-user-click-home-button
- https://android.stackexchange.com/a/57966
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()

So, your game should be paused when HOME is pressed and it's state should be the same it was before getting paused if it hasn't been destroyed yet by the phone.

You'll need to make sure your app data is not being destroyed while it's in background. I cannot help you with that because I'm not experienced with android development, but maybe this link could help:

[Android Application saving data when app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539042/android-application-saving-data-when-app-in-background)

***P.S.*** I'm gonna delete all the previous answers since I misunderstood you and they have no relation with what you need. (done)

Comment: i dont really understand, the example you are using is different from my codes

Comment: @Prodigy how do you know when the home button is pressed? The code that handles the home button events should not be paused.

Comment: i don't think i have a code that directly handles home button, i believe those are automatically handled by the android api

Comment: @Prodigy Oh, I completely misunderstood you, sorry. I thought you had a custom "home button" in your game but you meant the home button of android phones. I edited the answer, I hope that helps.